# Setting and reading instance variable value within rxJava chain from different Schedulers

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, rx-java, rx-java2

I am not sure about safety of reading/writing instance variables from rxJava chain with different schedulers. There is a small example

```java
public class RxJavaThreadSafety {

    private int variable = 0;

    // First call 
    public void doWriting() {
        Single.just(255)
                .doOnSuccess(
                        newValue -> variable = newValue
                )
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe();
    }

    // Second call
    public void doReadingRxChain() {
        Single.fromCallable((Callable<Integer>) () -> variable)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .subscribe(
                        result -> System.out.println(result)
                );
    }

    // Third call
    public void doReading() {
        System.out.println(variable);
    }

}
```

For simplicity lets assume that these three methods called one after another

**My question**: Does it thread safe to set variable "in" io scheduler, and lately read this variable "from" computation scheduler or main thread?

I think that is not thread safe, but i want some rxJava and concurrency experts to prove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not thread safe.

When you use `subscribeOn` it means that calling `subscribe()` adds the task for producing the item to the work queue of a scheduler.

The `doWriting()` and `doReadingRxChain()` methods add tasks to different schedulers. There is no guarantee that the chain in `doWriting()` will even start to run before `doReadingRxChain()`. This can happen for example if all IO threads are busy.

There is a more fundamental problem: you are writing the value of `variable` in one thread and reading it in another. Without any concurrency controls, nothing guarantees that the new value of `variable` is seen by the thread reading it. One way to fix that is declaring the variable as `volatile`:

```
private volatile int variable = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, actually my question was about concurrent visibility problem, i explained my question badly. I was curios about rxJava, if it somehow resolves visibility problem, your answer explained well.